# Google Apps Script: how to create an array of values for a given value by reading from a two column list?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, data-structures, google-sheets-formula

I have a set of data in a Google spreadsheet in two columns. One column is a list of article titles and the other is the ID of a hotel that is in that article. Call it list1.

[Example data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vjdZ0lXKTl1lk7sVT0FNv001LQYqIaNLCKwF_N2QKf0/edit#gid=1500410326)

I would like returned a new list with article titles in one column, and an array of the hotel IDs in that article in the other column.  Call it list2.

[Example data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vjdZ0lXKTl1lk7sVT0FNv001LQYqIaNLCKwF_N2QKf0/edit#gid=1500410326)

There are thousands of lines that this needs to be done for, and so my hope was to use Google Apps Script to help perform this task. My original thinking was to

1. Create column 1 of list2 which has the unique article titles (no script here, just the G-sheets `=unique()` formula.
2. Iterate through the titles in list2, looking for a match in first column of the list1
3. If there is a match:

   - retrieve its corresponding value in column 2
   - push it to an empty array in column two of list2
   - move onto next row in list1
4. if no longer a match, loop back to step 2.

I've written the following code. I am currently getting a type error (`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 13, file "Code")`), however, I wanted to ask whether this is even a valid approach to the problem?

```
function getHotelIds() {
  
  var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('list2');
  var lastRow = outputSheet.getLastRow();
  var data = outputSheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow,2).getValues();
  
  var workingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('list1');
  var lastActiveRow = workingSheet.getLastRow();
  var itemIDS = [];
  
  for (var i=1; i<=data.length; i++) {
    var currentArticle = data[i][0];
    var lookupArticle = workingSheet[i][0];
    if (currentArticle === lookupArticle) {
      var tempValue = [workingSheet[i][1]];
      itemIDS.push(tempValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (var i=1; i<=data.length; i++) {` The loop has a [tag:off-by-one] error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a simple google sheets formula:

You can use a very simple formula to achieve your goal instead of using long and complicated scripts.

Use `=unique(list1!A2:A)` in cell `A2` of `list2` sheet to get the unique hotels.

and then use this formula to all the unique hotels by dragging it down in column B.

`=JOIN(",",filter(list1!B:B,list1!A:A=A2))`

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - was hoping I didn't have to use GAS for this..!

Answer (score 2):

You got the idea right, but the logic needed some tweaking. The "undefined" error is caused by the `workingSheet[i][0]`. WorkingSheet is a [Sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), not an array of data. Also, is not necessary to get the data from **list2** (output), it is rather the opposite. You have to get the data from the **list1** (source) sheet instead, and iterate over it.

I added a new variable, `oldHotel`, which will be used to compare each line with the current hotel. If it's different, it means we have reached a different Hotel and the data should be written in **list2**.

```
function getHotelIds() {

    var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('list2');
    var outLastRow = outputSheet.getLastRow();

    var workingSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('list1');
    var lastActiveRow = workingSheet.getLastRow();
    var sourceValues = workingSheet.getRange("A2:B" + lastActiveRow).getValues();

    var itemIDS = [];
    var oldHotel = sourceValues[0][0]; //first hotel of the list

    for (var i = 0; i < sourceValues.length; i++) {

        if (sourceValues[i][0] == oldHotel) {

            itemIDS.push(sourceValues[i][1]);
            /*When we reach the end of the list, the oldHotel variable will never be different. So the next if condition is needed. Otherwise it wouldn't write down the last Hotel.
            */
            if (i == sourceValues.length - 1) {
                outputSheet.getRange(outLastRow + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([
                    [sourceValues[i][0], itemIDS.toString()]
                ]);
            }

        } else {

            outputSheet.getRange(outLastRow + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([
                [sourceValues[i - 1][0], itemIDS.toString()]
            ]);
            oldHotel = sourceValues[i][0]; //new Hotel will be compared
            outLastRow = outputSheet.getLastRow(); //lastrow has updated
            itemIDS = []; //clears the array to include the next codes
        }
    }
}
```

I also converted the `itemIDS` array to a String each time, so it's written down in a single cell without issues.

> Make sure each column of the Sheet is set to "Plain text" from **Format > Number > Plain Text**

**References**

- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - makes much more sense now. Have had a play and all works nicely. Have opted for the formula below, as want to keep it as simple as possible, but this is super useful nonetheless

Comment: I vote up this answer because it is indeed a very complete answer and great GAS alternative :)